How can I fix my add method to insert information into rest api database
I have a model class called Incident and of the attributes is assignee which is intended to hold a username that is coming from the model class User. When i test my api endpoint it sends back a 403 forbidden
package com.api.CyberSentry.models;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "incident")
public class Incident {

    @Id
    @JsonProperty(value = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty(value = "Title")
    private String title;

    @JsonProperty(value = "Description")
    private String description;

    @JsonProperty(value = "Affected Systems")
    private String affectedSystems;

    @JsonProperty(value = "Priority")
    private String priority;

    @JsonProperty(value = "Status")
    private String status;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "assignee_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User assignee;

    public Incident() {
    }

    public Incident(String title,
                    String description,
                    String affectedSystems,
                    String priority,
                    String status,
                    User assignee) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.affectedSystems = affectedSystems;
        this.priority = priority;
        this.status = status;
        this.assignee = assignee;
    }

    public Incident(Long id,
                    String title,
                    String description,
                    String affectedSystems,
                    String priority,
                    String status,
                    User assignee) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.affectedSystems = affectedSystems;
        this.priority = priority;
        this.status = status;
        this.assignee = assignee;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getAffectedSystems() {
        return affectedSystems;
    }

    public void setAffectedSystems(String affectedSystems) {
        this.affectedSystems = affectedSystems;
    }

    public String getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public void setPriority(String priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public User getAssignee() {
        return assignee;
    }

    public void setAssignee(User assignee) {
        this.assignee = assignee;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Incident{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", title='" + title + '\'' +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                ", affectedSystems='" + affectedSystems + '\'' +
                ", priority='" + priority + '\'' +
                ", status='" + status + '\'' +
                ", assignee=" + assignee +
                '}';
    }
}

package com.api.CyberSentry.service;

import com.api.CyberSentry.models.Incident;
import com.api.CyberSentry.models.User;
import com.api.CyberSentry.repository.IncidentRepository;
import com.api.CyberSentry.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class IncidentService {

    private final IncidentRepository incidentRepository;
    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    public IncidentService(IncidentRepository incidentRepository, UserRepository userRepository) {
        this.incidentRepository = incidentRepository;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    //Adding a new incident
    public Incident addIncident(Incident incident){
        User incidentAssignee = userRepository.findByUsername(incident.getAssignee().getUsername());

        if (incidentAssignee != null) {
            incident.setAssignee(incidentAssignee);
            try {
                return incidentRepository.save(incident);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to add new incident " + e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Username " + incident.getAssignee().getUsername() + "not found");
        }
    }

    //Get all incidents
    public List<Incident> getAllIncidents(){
        try {
            return incidentRepository.findAll();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException("Cannot retrieve all incidents " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    //Get a specific incident
    public Optional<Incident> getIncidentByTitle(String title){
        try{
            return getAllIncidents()
                    .stream()
                    .filter(Incident -> title.equals(Incident.getTitle()))
                    .findFirst();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException("Incident " + e.getMessage() + "not found");
        }
    }

    //Update incident
    public Optional<Incident> updateIncident(Long id, Incident incidentBeingUpdated){
        try{
            Optional<Incident> existingIncident = incidentRepository.findById(id);
            if (existingIncident.isPresent()){
                Incident existingIncident1 = existingIncident.get();
                existingIncident1.setTitle(incidentBeingUpdated.getTitle());
                existingIncident1.setDescription(incidentBeingUpdated.getDescription());
                existingIncident1.setAffectedSystems(incidentBeingUpdated.getAffectedSystems());
                existingIncident1.setPriority(incidentBeingUpdated.getPriority());
                existingIncident1.setStatus(incidentBeingUpdated.getStatus());
                existingIncident1.setAssignee(incidentBeingUpdated.getAssignee());

                Incident savedIncident = incidentRepository.save(incidentBeingUpdated);
                return Optional.of(savedIncident);
            }
            else {
                return Optional.empty();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to update incident " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    //Delete Incident
    public boolean deleteIncident(Long id){
        try {
            incidentRepository.deleteById(id);
            return true; //if successul
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to delete incident " + e.getMessage() + id);
        }
    }
}

package com.api.CyberSentry.models;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @JsonProperty(value = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty(value = "Email")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @JsonProperty(value = "Username")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String username;

    @JsonProperty(value = "Password")
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;

    public User() {
    }

    public User(String email, String username, String password) {
        this.email = email;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public User(Long id,
                String email,
                String username,
                String password) {
        this.id = id;
        this.email = email;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", email='" + email + '\'' +
                ", username='" + username + '\'' +
                ", password='" + password + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

package com.api.CyberSentry.controller;

import com.api.CyberSentry.models.Incident;
import com.api.CyberSentry.service.IncidentService;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class IncidentController {

    private final IncidentService incidentService;

    public IncidentController(IncidentService incidentService) {
        this.incidentService = incidentService;
    }

    //Create a new incident
    @PostMapping("/addIncident")
    public ResponseEntity<Incident> addIncident(@RequestBody Incident incident){
        Incident savedIncident = incidentService.addIncident(incident);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(savedIncident);
    }

    //Retrieve a single incident
    @GetMapping("/incidents/{title}")
    public ResponseEntity<Incident> getIncidentByTitle(@PathVariable String title){
        Optional<Incident> incidentOptional = incidentService.getIncidentByTitle(title);
        return incidentOptional.map(ResponseEntity::ok)
                .orElseGet(() -> ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
    }
    /*
    To add more retrieval end points as the project grows i.e. integration of front end

    - /incidents/{description}
    - /incidents/{affectedSystem}
    - /incidents/{priority}
    - /incidents/{status}
    - /incidents/{assignedTo}

     */

    //Retrieve all incidents
    @GetMapping("/incidents")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Incident>> getAllIncidents(){
        List<Incident> incidents = incidentService.getAllIncidents();
        return ResponseEntity.ok(incidents);
    }

    //Update Incident
    @PutMapping(path = "/incidents/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Incident> updateIncident(@PathVariable Long id,
                                                   @RequestBody Incident incident){
        Optional<Incident> updatedIncidentOptional = incidentService.updateIncident(id,incident);
        return updatedIncidentOptional.map(ResponseEntity::ok)
                .orElseGet(() -> ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
    }

    //Delete an incident
    @DeleteMapping(value = "/incidents/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<String> deleteIncident(@PathVariable Long id){
        boolean deleteStatus = incidentService.deleteIncident(id);
        if (deleteStatus){
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Incident of id " + id + "has been successfully deleted");
        }
        else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                    .body("Failed to delete incident of id " + id);
        }
    }
}

I tried debugging using AI but I couldn't get the problem solved. Hoping to get help from seasoned professionals. Newbie Rest API builder

When you test your endpoint how?  Exactly how did you call this?

Do you use spring security? BTW: Take care of java naming conventions. Package names should be lower case.

Please provide some log information
